# Updating front end during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a method that runs through a loop that can take quite a while to complete as it requires getting data back form an API.
What I would like to do is display a message on the front end explaining how the system is progressing during each loop. Is there a way to update the front end while processing?

```
      public static void GetScreenshot(List<string> urlList,    List<DesiredCapabilities> capabilities, String platform, Literal updateNote)
      {
        foreach (String url in urlList)
        {
          String siteName = new Uri(url).Host;

          String dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ "/Screenshots/" + siteName + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm");
          foreach (DesiredCapabilities cap in capabilities)
          {
            String saveDirectory = "";
            if (platform == "btnGenDesktopScreens")
            {
              saveDirectory = dir + "/" + cap.GetCapability("os") + "-" + cap.GetCapability("os_version") + "-" + cap.GetCapability("browser") + cap.GetCapability("browser_version");
            }
            else if(platform == "btnMobile")
            {
              saveDirectory = dir + "/" + cap.GetCapability("platform") + "" + cap.GetCapability("device") + "-" + cap.GetCapability("browserName");
            }
            updateNote.Text += "<br/>" + cap.GetCapability("platform") + " - " + cap.GetCapability("device") + "-" + cap.GetCapability("browserName");
//I'd like to display a message here
            TakeScreenshot(url, cap, saveDirectory);
//I'd like to display a message here
          }
        }
      }
```

Has anyone come across a method of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're returning the feedback to the user, you might be able to do this by using HttpResponse.Flush in a loop to push parts of the HTML response to the user a bit at a time.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for the response. I've trued adding that in after updating the text of the literal but to no avail.

Comment: Did you ensure output buffering is on as well, as per the example in the link?

Comment: Also I'm not convinced it will work if you're trying to put all the output into one literal. You'd be better creating a new literal for each loop and writing that to the output each time using Response.Write, and then calling the Flush method. Or even just writing the HTML directly to the response, without using a literal as an intermediary.

Comment: Yes I've enabled output buffering and tried a direct response.write. No luck.